# PHP regex - find and replace hashtag underscore with hyphen

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have an anchor tag href link like below :

```
<a href="#_what_are_classes">What are classes</a>
```

replace with using regexp

```
<a href="#what-are-classes">What are classes</a>
```

the same way change the DIV from

```
<div id="_what_are_classes" class="padTop"></div>
```

to using a regexp

```
<div id="what-are-classes" class="padTop"></div>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work for that

Comment: Is `_what_are_classes` a constant or could it be any word with underscores?

Comment: Do you want to replace **all** `<a href="blah_blah"...` and **all** `<div id="blah_blah"...`

Answer (score 2):

This will replace all `<a href` and all `<div id` that contain underscores.

```
$string = '<a href="#_what_are_classes">What are classes</a>

   <div id="_what_are_classes" class="padTop"></div>';

$res = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?:<a.*?href="|<div.*?id=")\K[^"]+/',
            function ($m) {
                // remove the # and _ at the beginning
                // then replace _ with -
                return str_replace('_','-',preg_replace('/^#?_/', '', $m[0]) );
            },
            $string);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="what-are-classes">What are classes</a>

   <div id="what-are-classes" class="padTop"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                 # start non capture group
    <a.*?href="     # a href
  |                 # OR
    <div.*?id="     # div id
)                   # end group
\K                  # forget all we have seen until this posiiton
[^"]+               # 1 or more not quote
```

Comment: works very good, thanks for saving my time...

Answer (score 1):

This function replaces the HTML attributes you mentioned, but you might have to tweak it for HTML outside of the examples you provided:

```
<?php

function convert_hrefs_and_ids($text) {
    $replace = static function($str) {
        $prefix = str_replace('_', '', $str[2]);
        $attribute = str_replace('_', '-', $str[3]);
        return $str[1] . '="' . $prefix . $attribute . '"';
    };
    $text = preg_replace_callback('/(a.+href)="(#_)([a-z0-9_]+)"/Ui', $replace, $text);
    $text = preg_replace_callback('/(div.+id)="(_)([a-z0-9_]+)"/Ui', $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

If you want to use it with Wordpress, you can take a look at the [Wordpress API for content filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) and use it like so:

```
<?php

add_filter('the_content', 'convert_hrefs_and_ids');
```